# export a collection that has an array as a field from mongodb to a csv

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

i'm trying to export data from a mongo db to a csv file.  the issue is that for a particular collection  (below).

i want to export the values in the array to the csv file, currently when i do the export the "results" field displays (in the csv file) "array[3]" as opposed to the values of the array.

```
 {"_id"    : ObjectId("527f2430e1542d0707000000"),       
 "results" : [
       {"description" : "description number 1"}, 
       {"description" : "description number 2"}, 
       {"description" : "description number 3"}]
}
```

a friend mentioned that i should look into MapReduce to handle this issue.

so my question is?  is mapreduce the way to go or is there another solution that i could look into to get the array data in the exported csv file?

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, map reduce will not help you with this. It is for making queries, not for exporting something. CSV is a text file format where every cell is marked with some sort of a delimiter (, or ; most often). So when you try to insert an array in one cell, mongo does not know what to do (and this is ok).

There is no native way to store complex data structure as a CSV (use [mongodump](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/program/mongodump/) to store your complex data). If you really need to store this as CSV you need to write you own script to iterate through all your data and come up with some appropriate format to store it.